# What to know for upgrading from Reporting Services 2000 to SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Not that it's a prerequisite for commenting here, but I'd like to pick the brain of someone that's taken their Reporting Services platform from 2000 to 2008 (skipping right over 2005).

The architecture between 2000 and 2005 (so thus between 2000 and 2008 also) changed significantly it seems, so I'd like to know what needs to be done (before,during,after) the process of taking my rs2000 install (installed on a web server running IIS 5, connecting to a remote sql server 2000 box that hosts the ReportServer/ReportServerTempDB databases) and converting it to SQL208 - where, from the looks of it, is hosted in some sort of it's own native hosting engine, no IIS needed (is that right?).

I've used [this tool](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) before, but only for moving stuff between 2 rs2000 databases. I'm curious if it works between 2000 and 2008. I've also been reading on TechNet and MSDN about some kind of "upgrade advisor" and "upgrade wizard" - but I remember what the VB6 to VB.NET Wizard was like, so I'm a little skeptical of a wizard that proclaims to help migrate stuff between 2 architecturally different versions of a product.

Disclaimer: I am not a Reporting Services (or SQL Server) admin. Just the guy on the team most familiar with installing/supporting the tool, so I'm stuck being responsible for this migration too - though I'm a veteran developer, not totally clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware, there is no anonymous mode in SRS 2008, you should use Active Directory / Kerberos / Windows authentication or use your own authentication module.

In SRS2008 you've got feature like Tablix/Matrix which are really usefull, maybe you can make some optimizations into your old reports.